# How to declare scalar variable in where condition?

Tags: sql, function

I am having Scalar variable in a function

```
@variable1 varchar(20)
```

Now, I want to frame a query as

```
select * from Table1 where columname ='Completed'
```

here

```
'columname' is nothing but a @variable1. then , how to declare that??
```

i tried with

```
select * from Table1 where @variable1='Completed'
```

but it showing error.

Example

```
create function func(@variable1 varchar(10))
returns @tble Table(tble varchar(50) null)
as
begin
declare @SQL varchar(100)
 set @SQL  = 'select * from Table1 where '+@variable1+'IN (Completed)'
 select @SQL 
 return
end
```

Comment: (1) `= NULL` never returns true.  (2) You cannot replace identifiers with parameters, you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: This is usually a sign of a broken data model - you have data stored in multiple columns, but those data items are of the same "type" such that you want to query over those multiple columns. This is usually an indication that it should have been a *single* column, with perhaps an additional column to store the *data* that is currently embedded in the column *names*.